# How to enable the spark SQL with %sql Magic string on Hive in pyspark using jupyter notebook

Tags: hive, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

[image]How to enable the `%sql Magic string` on jupyter notebook and how to use %sql magic string on a cell with the below line of code.

```
spark.sql('select * from test').show()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
%%sparksql
select * from test
```

Before trying install

> pip install sparksql-magic

Refer: https://github.com/cryeo/sparksql-magic

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the %sql magic string to work with Spark SQL. You need to first create a Spark DataFrame as described in the [SparkSession API docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession), like by using `df = createDataFrame(data)`. Then you would create a global view, calling `df.createOrReplaceTempView("test")`. Then your above query would work.

Comment: How to use the above query with %sql magic string in jupyter notebook, How to enable the spark SQL via %sql, Working like on databricks

Answer (score 1):

before using %%sparksql (in case you've installed sparksql-magic), you need to load the extension using below command in a separate cell.

```
 %load_ext sparksql_magic
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
%%sql
select * from test
```

Link 
https://github.com/jupyter-incubator/sparkmagic

Comment: sparkmagic can be installed but listing the magic strings on notebook %sql is not found, please see the above image.